# Xcode UILabel upside down

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6, core-graphics

I want to have a label which should be displayed upside down. That means after creating the label I want to turn it around 90 degrees. That works but now the label is anywhere. I don't know HOW the label is rotated. Maybe one could help me. The code is the following:

```
let label = CreatorClass.createLabelWithFrame(CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 15), text: "aString", size: 12.0, bold: false, textAlignment: .Left, textColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), addToView: self)
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

CreatorClass creates a label and add it to a certain view (it adds to self because this code is called in a subclass of `UIView`). Actually it's self-explanatory I think.

Comment: what do you mean? if you want to see how you can link `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` with your sender.

Comment: What do you mean by "That works but now label is anywhere."?  Upside down is 180 degrees, by the way, or `M_PI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you label rotate around its center, that means:

You label rotate around : x = 10 + 75 = 85
                            y = 10 + 7.5 = 17.5

This is also the center of the new position, what has a width of 15.0 and height of 150;

The new rect of your view, after the transfer is:

```
                       x = 85 - 7.5 = 77.5;
                       y = 17.5 - 75 = -57.5; 
                       width = 15 , height = 150.
```

It could be out of the self bounds.

You might want to go back your label to its init position, only need to put it to init position:

```
  label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 15, height: 150)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the label rotates around its center. Thank you very much :]